# django cannot link a user model and a corresponding from to be used in a template for sign up

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have a custom user model subclassing `AbstractBaseUser`:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):


    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

after migrating, I created a simple form for sign up which I am mapping two fields from the model: `email` and `name` like below:

```
class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['name', 'email']
```

I then have the `view` to render a `template` to show the above fields as input fields:

```
class MyRegisterView(RegisterView):

    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, "registration.html", context={"form": form})
```

and in the `template`, I am simply doing:

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
  <h3>Sign Up</h3>

  <div>
     <label for="name">
         <input id = "name" name = "name" class="textfield" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name">
     </label>
  </div>

  <div>
     <label for="email">
         <input id = "email" name = "email" class="textfield" type="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
      </label>
```

(also including `passwords` and so on)

The problem is that when I add the `name` field and then `submit`, the name field in the database is not getting populated (the `email` is and the user account is created... but without the `name`). Why is that?

below is my custom `BaseUserManager` that I am subclassing: ( could it be that I am missing something in the below `Usermanager`?)

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, name, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            name=name,
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, name, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(name, email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, name, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(name, email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: Why have you overridden `get` but not `post`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman just because I do not know what and how to override it. I am new to django. How would I override it to accept `name`? If you think that would solve the problem. let me know.

Comment: Where is RegisterView defined?

Comment: @DanielRoseman RegisterView is a DRF default view not mine